# How to make bot status show as "Online from Mobile"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I saw that NotSoBot has his status as online [on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiF4k.png), is there a way that I can do that in discord.js?

Answer (score 8):

I understand this is old, but an easier method would be to add this where you define client/bot

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ ws: { properties: { $browser: "Discord iOS" }} });
```

Comment: wait it's possible to do this without changing the src of discord.js? i never knew

Answer (score 3):

In discord.js v13, when you instantiate the client you can provide the `$browser` inside `ws` `properties`:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    // .. more intents as needed
  ],
  ws: { properties: { $browser: 'Discord iOS' } },
});
```

And in discord.js v14 it's just `browser` now:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    // .. more intents as needed
  ],
  ws: { properties: { browser: 'Discord iOS' } },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is undocumented but here you go nevertheless if you really want to do this you must go to the Constants.js file.
Under the node_modules folder, either if you're using something like Visual Studio Code or just go directly to the file, navigate to "src", then "util", then find the Constants.js file. Once there scroll down until you see "ws:" it should look something like this:

```
  ws: {
    large_threshold: 250,
    compress: require('os').platform() !== 'browser',
    properties: {
      $os: process ? process.platform : 'discord.js',
      $browser: 'discord.js',
      $device: 'discord.js',
      $referrer: '',
      $referring_domain: '',
    },
    version: 6,
  },
```

Change

```
$browser: 'discord.js',
```

to

```
$browser: 'Discord iOS',
```

And then start your bot, it should have a small phone icon next to its avatar. Hope this helps.

Comment: But what if I don't have `ws:` in my `Constants.js` file?

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution for the latest version of discord.js at the moment (discord.js@14.13.0)

```js
const { 
    DefaultWebSocketManagerOptions: { 
        identifyProperties 
    } 
} = require("@discordjs/ws");

identifyProperties.browser = "Discord Android"; // or "Discord iOS"
```

**Please note**: this approach is not documented and is not endorsed by **Discord API** and **discord.js**.

The code above modifies the `browser` property of the `identifyProperties` object. The value of the `browser` property should be the **name of the library**, according to the [Discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway-events#identify-identify-connection-properties).

We change this property to `"Discord Android"` or `"Discord iOS"`, thus getting the status "online from mobile". This is a dirty trick.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding `{ ws: { properties: { browser: "Discord iOS" }} }` or similar things into my code, however, it didn't work for me... Not in the latest discord.js v14 at least. Adding or removing the `$` sign infront of `browser` didn't change things for me as well.

My solution: Import `DefaultWebSocketManagerOptions` and change the value from there as follows:

```js
const { Client, DefaultWebSocketManagerOptions } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    // your intents here
  ]
});

DefaultWebSocketManagerOptions.identifyProperties.browser = 'Discord iOS'; // Sets it for EVERY new Client(...)

client.login(...);
```

Worked like a charm on my project and I don't have to change the contents of the `node_modules` folder like other people did. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is undocumented but here you go nevertheless if you really want to do this you must go to the Constants.js file. Under the `node_modules` folder, either if you're using something like Visual Studio Code or just go directly to the file, navigate to "src", then "util", then find the Option.js file. Once there scroll down until you see "ws:" it should look something like this:
Go In

`node_module/discord.js/src/utill/Options.js` And Scroll Down You See

```
ws: {
  large_threshold: 250,
  compress: require('os').platform() !== 'browser',
  properties: {
    $os: process ? process.platform : 'discord.js',
    $browser: 'discord.js',
    $device: 'discord.js',
    $referrer: '',
    $referring_domain: '',
  },
  version: 6,
},
```

Change `$browser: 'discord.js'` to `$browser: 'Discord Android'`.
Or You Can Set Discord Ios

Or you can put this code on your main file

```
const Options = require('discord.js/src/util/Options.js');
Options.DefaultOptions.ws.properties.$browser = `Discord Android`
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:
Change the $browser

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ ws: { properties: { $browser: "Discord iOS" }} });
```

To browser:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ ws: { properties: { browser: "Discord iOS" }} });
```

If you check the constants.js file, the sections are: ws > properties > browser, at no time is there a $

[discord.js v13, v14]

Comment: Nope. In v13 it's `$browser` and in v14 there is no $ sign, so just `browser`. And in neither of those versions are these settings in the `Constants.js` file but the `Options.js`.

Comment: I've checked the files and tested if it works and if it works without the $ and fails with the $, you're wrong.

Comment: Sure, sure... :) Or you've just misread something in my comment. I'm right though.