# Is there any way I can set my Discord Bot's online status to mobile on discord.js v13?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The methods used in previous versions of Discord.js don't seem to work in V13

I have tried using this code but it did not work

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ ws: { properties: { $browser: "Discord iOS" }} });
```

I also could not find the code used to set it in `Constants.js` file
File path: `/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Constants.js`

Code reference: [How to set a bot active on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411593/how-to-set-a-bot-active-on-mobile/64863340)

Comment: Works for me - I used that exact code

Comment: Both `Discord Android` and `Discord iOS` should work. It might take a few minutes to change or it could be cache on your side. Restart your Discord desktop app / browser. Also you shouldn't change the package code just like that (it might break things when you update the package) unless you truly need it.

Answer (score 0):

just put that code in index.js like this:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
    ws: { properties: { $browser: "Discord iOS" }}
});
```

Comment: Please explain the reason as of why this would be a solution.